# Preserve case while using JSON2POJO maven latest version

Tags: jsonschema2pojo

I have some JSON as below

```
{
  "FName": "Test",
  "LName": "Test"
}
```

When i use json2pojo maven plugin(0.4.37), the POJOs are created with the proper Java naming conventions(like `fName,lName`). Is there a way to override this and create the POJOs with the same names (like `FName, LName`).

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

Annotate your fields with `@JsonProperty()` annotation

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;    
class SomeClass {
  @JsonProperty("FName")
  private String fName;

  @JsonProperty("LName")
  @private String lName;

  //getters and setters 
}
```